# Databind listbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listbox, data-binding

I'm pretty new to asp net 2.0 programming and I was wondering how can I add an "all" item to a listbox, so I can filter my results by a specific criteria ( from a database ) or display all the results.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to modify the DataSource of the control that relies on the selection in the ListBox:

1. In the Databound event of the ListBox, insert a ListItem at position 0 with text 'ALL' and value '%'
2. Arrange your datasource (in my case SQLDataSource) to include the following condition:

   [ColumnName] LIKE @ColumnName
3. Add a Parameter to the DataSource for the object that depends on the selection in the ListBox:

   `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListBoxID" Name="ColumnName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />`

Comment: Perfect, can you please give me an example of how to add it at position 0 in the databound event?
I did this:
protected void txtCiudad_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtCiudad.Items.Add(new ListItem("Todas", "%"));
}
but I can't define the index. thanks